# How to login to Xamarin component store using visual studio 2013

Tags: android, visual-studio-2013, xamarin

After right click on **components** directory which is in **solution** and choose **Get more components**, this dialog box appears:
[Dialog box in visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ax4cy.jpg)

Then in order to login my xamarin account I click on **Login to your xamarin account** so I get this web page:
[Login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFVfa.jpg)

So After I click on login button I get success message and it tells me return back to visual studio

But when I return back to visual studio and try one more time, nothing happens, So what's the problem?